# MySQL CASE with SUM function

Tags: mysql, case

Is it possible to use the result of SUM in a case? My current query is like this:

```
SELECT USERNAME, SUM(AMOUNT),
CASE SUM(AMOUNT)
WHEN SUM(AMOUNT) = 0.0 THEN 1
WHEN SUM(AMOUNT) < 50.0 THEN 2
WHEN SUM(AMOUNT) > 75.0 THEN 4
END AS gid, 0 FROM payments GROUP BY USERNAME;
```

That looks fine to me, but generates this:

censored    13.00   NULL    0

Is it even possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the constraints on the aggregate functions, as mentioned in [*Marc B's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21610619/767881), an alternate solution is to fetch the records first and then apply aggregate functions on the desired fields.

```
SELECT 
  USERNAME, 
  SUM_AMOUNT,
  CASE 
    WHEN SUM_AMOUNT = 0 THEN 1
    WHEN SUM_AMOUNT < 50 THEN 2
    WHEN SUM_AMOUNT > 75 THEN 4
    END AS gid,
  0
FROM (
  SELECT USERNAME, SUM(AMOUNT) SUM_AMOUNT,
  FROM payments
  GROUP BY USERNAME
) USER_AMOUNTS
```

Answer (score 1):

Not possible like this - Aggregate functions are calculated AFTER the whole result set is known, but case is evaluated at the per-row level.

You need to this in a `HAVING` clause.